# JavaScript Sortable do function on list changes?

Tags: javascript, html, sortablejs

How can I make a function fire when a sortable list changes?

I have looked for some examples but they are making the lists different to how I am and I cant see how to do it with how my sortable lists are generated. Perhaps I am using a different Sortable version or something?

This is how I make my lists...

```
<script>

    Sortable.create(plansList, {
        animation: 100,
        group: 'list-1',
        draggable: '.recipe',
        handle: '.handle',
        sort: true,
        filter: '.sortable-disabled',
        chosenClass: 'active'
    });

    Sortable.create(suggestionsList, {
        animation: 100,
        group: 'list-1',
        draggable: '.recipe',
        handle: '.handle',
        sort: true,
        filter: '.sortable-disabled',
        chosenClass: 'active'
    });

</script>
```

As you can see I have 2 lists. I want both to fire the same function when they change, but if both lists change (because an item was moved from one list to the other) I don't want the function to fire twice.

Can anyone help?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event `onEnd` will only fire once, as requested. But it will fire if also no change has been made. So you might need to compare old index to new index.

```js
var example2Left = document.querySelector("#example2-left");
var example2Right = document.querySelector("#example2-right");

new Sortable(example2Left, {
  group: 'shared', // set both lists to same group
  animation: 150,
  onEnd: foo
});
new Sortable(example2Right, {
  group: 'shared',
  animation: 150,
  onEnd: foo
});

function foo(ev) {
  var to = ev.to;
  var from = ev.from;
  var oldIndex = ev.oldIndex;
  var newIndex = ev.newIndex;

  if (to != from || oldIndex != newIndex) {
    singleOnChange(ev)
  }
}

function singleOnChange(ev) {
  console.log("list(s) changed")
}
```

```css
.col {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.list-group-item {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 2px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Sortable/1.15.0/Sortable.min.js" integrity="sha512-Eezs+g9Lq4TCCq0wae01s9PuNWzHYoCMkE97e2qdkYthpI0pzC3UGB03lgEHn2XM85hDOUF6qgqqszs+iXU4UA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div id="example2-left" class="list-group col">
  <div class="list-group-item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="list-group-item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="list-group-item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="list-group-item">Item 4</div>
  <div class="list-group-item">Item 5</div>
  <div class="list-group-item">Item 6</div>
</div>

<div id="example2-right" class="list-group col">
  <div class="list-group-item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="list-group-item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="list-group-item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="list-group-item">Item 4</div>
  <div class="list-group-item">Item 5</div>
  <div class="list-group-item">Item 6</div>
</div>
```